# How to add jar files to $SPARK_HOME/jars correctly?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have used this command and it works fine:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Apptest')\
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.5').getOrCreate()
```

But I'd like to download the jar file and always start with:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Apptest').getOrCreate()
```

How can I do it? I have tried:

1. Move to SPARK_HOME jar dir:

   cd /de/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/jars
2. Download jar file

   curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.3.5/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.5.jar --output mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.5.jar

But spark don't see it. I got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
```

I know there is .`/spark-shell --jar` command, but I am using jupyter notebook. Is there some step missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was looking for is `.config("spark.jars","..")`:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test')\
.config("spark.jars", "/root/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.5.jar,/root/mongo-java-driver-3.12.5.jar") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Or:

```
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"]="--jars /root/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.5.jar,/root/mongo-java-driver-3.12.5.jar pyspark-shell"
```

Also, seems that only put the jar files in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` works fine as well, but in my case and question example was missing the dependency `mongo-java-driver-3.12.5.jar`. After download all dependencies in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` I was able to run only with:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()
```

I have find out the dependencies in: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `SparkSession` in the jupyter notebook, unfortunately you have to use the `.config('spark.jars.packages', '...')` to add the jars that you want when you're creating the spark object.

Instead, if you want to add the jar in "default" mode when you launch the notebook, I would recommend you to create a custom kernel, so that every time when you create a new notebook, you even don't need to create the `spark`. If you're using Anaconda, you can check the docs: https://docs.anaconda.com/ae-notebooks/admin-guide/install/config/custom-pyspark-kernel/

Comment: `Since you're using SparkSession....`, could you show where this is documented?